# Trying to add more than 1 jQuery ui-datepicker to application. Only allows for 1 with current code

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm attempting to add more than one calendar pop-up using the jQuery ui-datepicker plugin.

Currently, only 1 calendar will appear, I would like to have a second calendar appear on the same page.

**HTML /views/pages/index.html.erb**

```
<label class="label_field" for="drop_off">Drop-Off</label>
<input id="datepicker" class="input_field" type="text" name="drop_off">

<label class="label_field" for="pick_up">Pick-Up</label>
<input id="datepicker" class="input_field" type="text" name="pick_up">
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application'%>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>


<%= yield %>


  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS pages.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<label class="label_field" for="drop_off">Drop-Off</label>
<input id="datepicker1" class="input_field datepicker" type="text" name="drop_off">

<label class="label_field" for="pick_up">Pick-Up</label>
<input id="datepicker2" class="input_field datepicker" type="text" name="pick_up">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y4db5aLw/

As I mentioned previously in the comments, I would recommend using css class selector instead of ID.

Answer (score 1):

Change your input-element IDs (they must be unique)

```
...
<input id="datepicker1" class="input_field" type="text" name="drop_off">

...
<input id="datepicker2" class="input_field" type="text" name="pick_up">
```

Then instantiate datepickers against each:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I actually attempted that previously without any luck. I tried again and still get the same results. Only "datepicker1" will appear and "datepicker2" continues to be absent.

Comment: I would recommend addding css class to the elements and associate them with datepicker. This way you can have multiple instances working by just adding the class instead of specifying the ids.

Comment: @DinoMyte You have solved the problem. I changed my id="datepicker" to class="datepicker" and made the appropriate changes in the JS file as well. Now 2 calendars appear. Thank you, sir.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as accepted it it solved your original problem. Thanks